# Error in merge sorting of linked list

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a merge sorting practice on linked list sort and I couldn't figure the reason that the code doesn't work, my compiler doesn't give any useful error message. Can't someone point it out for me? thanks!

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct listnode { struct listnode * next; int key; };

    //function prototypes

    void seperate(struct listnode * node, struct listnode ** front, struct listnode ** back);

    struct listnode * merge(struct listnode * node_1, struct listnode * node_2);

    //merge sorted seperated linked list
    void mergeSort(struct listnode ** node)
    {
    struct listnode * head = * node; struct listnode * node_1; struct listnode * node_2;

    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL)) { return; }

    seperate(head, &node_1, &node_2);
    mergeSort(&node_1); mergeSort(&node_2);
    * node = merge(node_1, node_2);

}

//sort sepearted linked list
struct listnode * merge(struct listnode * node_1, listnode * node_2)
{
    struct listnode * return_result = NULL;
    if (node_1 == NULL) { return (node_2); }
    else if (node_2 = NULL) { return (node_1); }

    if (node_1->key <= node_2->key)
    {
        return_result = node_1; return_result->next = merge(node_1->next, node_2);
    }
    else { return_result = node_2; return_result->next = merge(node_1, node_2->next); }

    return return_result;

}

//function to seperate linked list 
void seperate(struct listnode * node, struct listnode ** front, struct listnode ** back)
{
    struct listnode * fast; struct listnode * slow;

    if (node == NULL || node->next == NULL) { *front = node; * back = NULL; }

    else
    {
        slow = node; fast = node->next;

        while (fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            if (fast != NULL) { slow = slow->next; fast = fast->next; }
        }

        * front = node; * back = slow->next; slow->next = NULL;

    }


}// merge sort of linked list completed



 //test functions to push and print the linked list  

void push(struct listnode ** head, int data)
{
    struct listnode * added_node = (struct listnode * )malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
    added_node->key = data;
    added_node->next = (*head);
    (*head) = added_node;
}

void printList(struct listnode * node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        cout << node->key;
        node = node->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct listnode * node1 = NULL;

    push(&node1, 3); push(&node1, 30); push(&node1, 23); push(&node1, 1); push(&node1, 0); push(&node1, 9);
    mergeSort(&node1);
    cout << endl;
    printList(node1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say 'the code doesn't work', what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I get a Segmentation fault but I couldn't figure out where that could be.

Comment: *my compiler doesn't give any useful error message.*  -- The compiler's job is to ensure that your program is syntactically correct.  The job of finding *logical* errors is up to you and your debugger / debugging sessions.

Comment: I see. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: On the line of "more careful" and "compiler doesn't give any useful error message" - use `-Wall` and keep your eyes peeled for warnings too. In spite of [criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Criticism), in regards to a consistent coding style, a follower of master Yoda am I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (node_1 == NULL) { return (node_2); }
else if (node_2 = NULL) { return (node_1); }
/// -----------^ this is an assignment here
```

To Yoda introduce you I will

```
if (NULL == node_1) { return (node_2); }
else if (NULL=node_2) { return (node_1); }
/// ---------^ still an assignment, 
//   but try it out & C what the compiler has to say
```

Comment: nvm lol ..... . I see it

Comment: Thanks guys.   I figured  my stupid mistake.

Comment: @user6820297 Care to accept the answer then?

Comment: sure. I didn't know there was a check mark there~

Comment: @user6820297 Thanks. Welcome to SO